# Verbose in model.fit with tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

How to get model.fit verbose in TensorFlow.js

I already try:

```
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {
    verbose: 1,
    epochs: 1000,
    shuffle: true
  });
```

and

```
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {
    verbose: 2,
    epochs: 1000,
    shuffle: true
  });
```

and

```
  await model.fit(xs, ys, verbose=1, {
    epochs: 1000,
    shuffle: true
  });
```

and

```
  await model.fit(xs, ys, true, {
    epochs: 1000,
    shuffle: true
  });
```

But nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should use "tfvis" to verbose in tf.js